# Python Pandas - sumif in excel - criteria and range same df volumn

Tags: python, pandas

I’ve been trying to code python equivalent of excel sumif

Excel:

```
Sumif($A$1:$A$20,A1,$C$1:$C$20)
```

---

```
enter code here

Pandas df:
A  C    Term
1  10   1
1  20   2
1  10   3
1  10   4
2  30   5
2  30   6
2  30   7
3  20   8
3  10   9
3  10   10
3  10   11
3  10   12
```

Output df - I want output df with ‘fwdSum’ as follows
—————————

```
A  C    Term  fwdSum
1  10   1      50
1  20   2      50
1  10   3      50
1  10   4      50
2  30   5      90
2  30   6      90
2  30   7      90
3  20   8      60
3  10   9      60
3  10   10     60
3  10   11     60
3  10   12     60
```

I tried creating another df with groupby and sum and then later merge
Please can anyone suggest the best Way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['fwdSum'] = df.groupby('A')['C'].transform('sum')
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    A   C  Term  fwdSum
0   1  10     1      50
1   1  20     2      50
2   1  10     3      50
3   1  10     4      50
4   2  30     5      90
5   2  30     6      90
6   2  30     7      90
7   3  20     8      60
8   3  10     9      60
9   3  10    10      60
10  3  10    11      60
11  3  10    12      60
```